# socket.broadcast.to isn't received by any client in the room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I cannot get to broadcast an event to a specific room.

I check the clients that are in the room, and they seem to have properly join the room.

However `socket.broadcast.to(socket.roomChannel).emit("cardSelected", cardInfo)` 
is simply not working,

whereas `socket.broadcast.emit("cardSelected", cardInfo)` works (but I need to broadcast only to the room).

This is driving me insane...
Here is my code, the part that is not working is all the way to the bottom:

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = '4000';

server.listen(port, function () {
});

this.rooms = [];

let lastRoomId = 0
let lastPlayerId = 0

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // send list of rooms at connect
    socket.emit("connected", {rooms: this.rooms});
    socket.id = ++lastPlayerId;

    // Room
    socket.on('createRoom', (roomName) => {
        const room = {
            id: ++lastRoomId,
            name: roomName,
            players: [],
        }
        this.rooms.push(room);
        socket.emit("roomCreated", room);
        socket.broadcast.emit("update_rooms", {rooms: this.rooms});
    });

    socket.on('joinRoom', (id) => {
        const index = this.rooms.map(room => room.id).indexOf(id);
        if (index >= 0) {
            this.rooms[index].players.push(socket.id);
            socket.emit("roomJoined", this.rooms[index]);

            socket.roomId = id;
            socket.roomChannel = this.rooms[index].name;

            socket.join(socket.roomChannel);

            socket.broadcast.emit("update_rooms", {rooms: this.rooms});
        }
    });


    // Game
    socket.on('cardSelected', (cardInfo) => {
        console.log("broadcasting to", socket.roomChannel);
        console.log("socket room", socket.rooms);

        var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomChannel].sockets;
       // Shows that the clients ARE in the room
       // returns "{ '1': true, '2': true }" if I have two clients
        console.log(clients); 

        // DOESNT WORK!!
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.roomChannel).emit("cardSelected", cardInfo)
        // DOESNT WORK!!
        io.to(socket.roomChannel).emit("cardSelected");

        // Works
        socket.broadcast.emit("cardSelected", cardInfo);
    });
});
```

I also tried `socket.to(socket.roomChannel).emit("cardSelected", cardInfo);` (without broadcast), without any success

Comment: Are you sure you have other sockets in that same room besides the one doing the broadcast?  Are you sure that `socket.roomChannel` contains the right value?

Comment: Yes, as I showed in the code, `var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.roomChannel].sockets;
       // Shows that the clients ARE in the room
       // returns "{ '1': true, '2': true }" if I have two clients
        console.log(clients); `

Comment: Did you step through it in the debugger and see what it's doing?  That's what I would do.

Comment: You mean step through the "emit" function?

Comment: Well, the interesting part to your question is probably occurring in the `socket.broadcast.to(socket.roomChannel)` part of your operation.  That's where it decided what clients it is going to send to.  And, yes I meant to step through that and watch what it is doing and which sockets it selects and why.  The beauty of open source and non-compiled code is that you just debug right into it and see what it is doing and why.

Comment: I didn't even think about debug the package itself, I was sure it would be way over my league. It turns out it was not :) Thank you for giving me the little push that helped me solve it (will post the solution in a second)

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the code inside socket.io, I found out that changing the value of "id" for the socket was breaking everything!

I removed this line `socket.id = ++lastPlayerId;` and now everything works fine :)

So, remember: **Never manually change the id of a socket**.

Comment: Yep, the `id` value is how socket.io keeps track of which sockets are in which rooms.  If you change that, you can break rooms.  I guess `"{ '1': true, '2': true }"` should have been the clue as you were apparently assigning `1` and `2` as id values.  Glad you now feel confident enough to debug right into other code libraries.  You will be able to solve lots of future problems this way and learn a lot when doing it.

Comment: FYI, after an appropriate amount of time, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it hasn't been long enough :) Thanks for the reminder